# C++ Linking Static Library against Shared Library

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, linker, shared-libraries

I am trying to build a plugin based application in C++.

I have two targets - base and plugin.

This is a portion of my CMakeLists.txt that does the main work

```
# Executables
# build plugin
file (GLOB SRCP "plugin/*.?pp")
include_directories(plugin/)
MESSAGE ( STATUS "SRC: " "${SRCP}" )
add_library(testplugin MODULE ${SRCP} )
add_dependencies( testplugin ${DEPS_TARGETS})
#target_link_libraries( testplugin dlib::dlib )
#build main
file( GLOB SRC "*.?pp" )
message( STATUS "SRC: " "${SRC}" )
add_executable( exec ${SRC} )
add_dependencies( exec ${DEPS_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries( exec dlib::dlib )
```

It builds successfully but when I try to load the plugin, it fails with this error

> Error: Cannot load library: libtestplugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4dlib6loggerD1Ev

That symbol corresponds to a statement in the plugin `dlib::logger dlog("main.abstract_cnn");`

dlib is a static library which I am using in both the base and the plugin. 
 I link this library to the base application but I don't know how to **link** it to a library/module?  Won't the base application pass on the symbols to the plugin?  What can I do in this situation?

I would also like a cross-platform solution.  Mainly linux+windows.

Can anyone advise? Please?

**How I am Loading**
I am using a library called Libsourcey which has a module called pluga for easy loading.  My program is the basic test program given here [pluga](https://sourcey.com/building-a-simple-cpp-cross-platform-plugin-system/).  It works for me, but when I try to include a 3rd party library I am stuck.

If anyone could point to resources that explain how to use 3rd party libraries in plugins, it would be great!

Comment: You link shared libraries just like you link executable programs. That `target_link_libraries` that you commented out for the shared library, what happens if you actually let CMake run it?

Comment: i tried that, but I get this error `/usr/bin/ld: deps_build/dlib_build/libdlib.a(logger_kernel_1.cpp.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against '.bss' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC`

Comment: Okay, that's a problem. Then you need to tell us how you *load* the "plugin"? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: Try linking your executable with `-rdynamic` flag, that might export the missing symbol.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin do you mean compile the base with that flag? how to specify that in cmake?

Answer (score 1):

**SOLVED!**

I added this to my cmake file `set(CMAKE_POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)` which is what the error message was trying to tell me (compile with `-fPIC`).
I did that and now I am able to link my plugin against the static library.